# php string function arguments that not in double quotation

Tags: php, function

I have a function that takes a string parameter. Can I pass a parameter to a function which isn't wrapped in single or double quotes?

```
public function getId($Name){
    //someCode
}
```

**Example Usage**

```
getId(MrBean);
```

VS

```
getId("MrBean");
```

Comment: Could your rewrite the bit after the comma to make it clearer? **Edit** Ah the code makes it clearer, *AFAIK* you can only do that if it is a constant.

Comment: I don't understand this question at all. Can you get someone to help you translate to English?

Comment: Strings are placed in quotes, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Script47 - awesome, let's see if the author actually meant to ask that :)

Comment: how bout `define('MrBean', 'MrBean');`

Comment: @ConradWarhol that would work, but the OP (I'm assuming) wants to output any string without quotes, which goes against how PHP works.

Comment: You can do it, just try it. Just make sure you have the constant defined

Comment: @Script47 do you think this would be satisfactory for the OP? `define('MrBean',chr(77).chr(114).chr(66).chr(101).chr(97).chr(110));` ;)

Comment: @Script47 is right - you could do it but it will throw errors though not terminate execution. Text  without quotes can be confused with constants by PHP  - text passed should always be in single or double quotes though variables should not be enclosed in quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't need to wrap the paramater in quotes.

```
function MrBean(){
    echo 'MrBean called<br/>';
}

function getId($func){
    echo 'getId called<br/>';
    $func();
}

getId(MrBean);
```